# request.getSession().getId() vs request.getRequestedSessionId()

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, httpsession

What is the difference between `request.getSession().getId()` and `request.getRequestedSessionId()`? Do both of them return the same thing i.e. Session Id?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`request.getRequestedSessionId()` will return the session id specified by the client (presumably in a cookie). `request.getSession().getId()` will return the server's session id (if a session does not exist, `request.getSession()` will create it).

The important difference is that you can't rely on the value returned by `request.getRequestedSessionId()`, since it may not be valid. From the documentation:

> Returns the session ID specified by the client. This may not be the same as the ID of the current valid session for this request. If the client did not specify a session ID, this method returns null.

Comment: Would anything be achieved by checking if they match or not?

Comment: It's hard to say tbh. Perhaps if you gathered metrics on how these values behave normally, you could detect anomalies in that behaviour, that could potentially be attacks on your application. But this is a big what-if.

Comment: why session ID of client may not be same as the ID of the current valid session for this request? (assuming session is still valid on client side)

Comment: I imagine that in most cases the values are the same, but I would never assume it.

Answer (score 3):

`HttpRequest.getRequestedSessionId()` is the session id provided by the caller, usually with the JESSIONID cookie whereas  `HttpRequest.getSession().getId()` is the id effectively used by the server.

For an ongoing session, the JESSIONID cookie, or the value of `HttpRequest.getRequestedSessionId()` allows the server to find the ongoing session by id.

For new sessions, you might be very tempted to set the servers session id by supplying a value via the JESSIONID cookie, i.e. the value of `HttpRequest.getRequestedSessionId()`. This would make it easy to correlate a chain of calls to multiple servers initiated by an initial call from the customer's browser. However, the semantics of HttpRequest.getRequestedSessionId() does not allow such chaining.
Indeed, the JESSIONID cookie has an effect only for a session already existing in the server and which was previously sent to the client. If the JESSIONID cookie refers to a nonexistent session id, the server creates a new session **ignoring** the value of JESSIONID cookie.

You can convince yourself of the above, by reading the source code of the `doGetSession(boolean)` in the `org.apache.catalina.connector.Request` class.